# Error with @prisma/client when deploying Azure Function using Azure DevOps

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-devops, azure-functions, prisma

I'm trying to deploy an Azure Function with Node.js and TypeScript using Azure DevOps.

My project uses Prisma to connect to a MongoDB database.
When I try to deploy my function, I encounter the following error:

```
@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
```

However, Prisma works fine on my local machine. I believe this is a Prisma-related issue, as another function that doesn't use Prisma deploys successfully.

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "testtsnode",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "prestart": "npx prisma generate && npm run build",
    "start": "func start",
    "test": "echo \"No tests yet...\"",
    "prisma:g": "npx prisma generate",
    "prisma:s": "npx prisma studio"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^4.11.0",
    "mongodb": "^5.1.0",
    "tsc-silent": "^1.2.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@azure/functions": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^16.x",
    "typescript": "^4.0.0"
  }
}
```

[Here's my devops setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AunuM.png)

Here's my devops setting in yaml format

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- bash: |
   if [ -f extensions.csproj ]
   then
       dotnet build extensions.csproj --output ./bin
   fi
  displayName: 'Build extensions'

- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node version 18.15.0'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 18.15.0

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Install Application Dependencies'
  inputs:
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    verbose: false

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Run ''build'' script'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'run build --if-present'

- task: Npm@1
  displayName: 'Remove extraneous packages'
  inputs:
    command: custom
    workingDir: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    verbose: false
    customCommand: 'prune --production'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive files'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false

- task: AzureFunctionApp@2
  displayName: 'Azure Function App Deploy'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: DevOps
    appType: functionAppLinux
    appName: tsnodefunction20230315
    package: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip'
```

I had try add npx prisma generate in postinstall and prestart.
I had also try change the output location of prisma generate
Both of above not working.

How can I resolve this error when deploying my Azure Function using Azure DevOps?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For prisma did not initialized error:

```
@prisma/client did not initialize yet. Please run "prisma generate" and try to import it again.
```

I included the npx prisma generate command inside the build script

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "npx prisma generate && nest build",
    ...
}
```

You're also following a similar way. This is what solved my issue on running docker image on spinnaker.